# Epub source code issue during extraction

Tags: epub, drm, fairplay

I'm trying to 'see' the source code for an interactive ebook (.epub) that I have on my ipad and it is running fine on Ibooks app.

What I did is changing the ebook's file extention .epub to .zip and unzipping it.
The problem is that whenever i try to open the files inside the epub folder they are completely messed up:

[image]

where is the problem?
(The book I tested with is on itunes store "the wind and the sun")

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it isn't about programming, durgh.


Answer (score 2, accepted):

The book is encrypted using [Apple's FairPlay DRM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FairPlay).